# Correct flow of a VSS backup - VSS_E_BAD_STATE error

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm having issues getting a backup job working in VSS and C++. It is now at the point of working and backing up files but it fails when I call `BackupComplete()` with the result `VSS_E_BAD_STATE` so I would like some input from anyone familiar with VSS on whether my flow is correct. I'm currently doing the following:

```
if( !CHECK_HRESULT(::CreateVssBackupComponents(&m_pBackupComponents))  )
{
    throw;
}

if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->InitializeForBackup())) )
{
    throw;
}

WCHAR wszVolumePathName[MAX_PATH];
GUID snapshotId;
BOOL supported = TRUE;
HRESULT hr;
SnapshotMap::iterator it;
BOOL bWorked = ::GetVolumePathName(path.c_str(), wszVolumePathName, MAX_PATH); 

if( !bWorked )
{
    throw;
}

if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->IsVolumeSupported(GUID_NULL, wszVolumePathName, &supported))) || !supported )
{
    throw;
}

GUID snapshotSetId;
if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->StartSnapshotSet(&snapshotSetId))) )
{
    throw;
}

m_SnapshotIdList.push_back(snapshotId);

if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->AddToSnapshotSet(wszVolumePathName, GUID_NULL, &snapshotId))) )
{
    throw;
}

if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->SetBackupState(FALSE, FALSE, VSS_BT_COPY, FALSE))) )
{
    throw;
}

CComPtr<IVssAsync> pPrepareForBackupResults; 
if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->PrepareForBackup(&pPrepareForBackupResults))) )
{
    throw;
}

if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = pPrepareForBackupResults->Wait())) )
{
    pPrepareForBackupResults.Release();
    throw;
}

HRESULT hrPrepareForBackupResults; 
if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = pPrepareForBackupResults->QueryStatus(&hrPrepareForBackupResults, NULL))) )
{
    pPrepareForBackupResults.Release();
    throw;
}

pPrepareForBackupResults.Release();
if( hrPrepareForBackupResults != VSS_S_ASYNC_FINISHED )
{
    throw;
}

CComPtr<IVssAsync> pDoSnapshotSetResults;
if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->DoSnapshotSet(&pDoSnapshotSetResults))) )
{
    throw;
}

m_VssSyncList.push_back(pDoSnapshotSetResults);

VSS_SNAPSHOT_PROP snapshotProperties;
if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->GetSnapshotProperties(snapshotId, &snapshotProperties))) )
{
    throw;
}

TSTRING newPath(snapshotProperties.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject);
m_SnapshotMap.insert(SnapshotMap_Entry(TSTRING(wszVolumePathName), newPath));
newPath.append(path.substr(2));

<Backup files here>

::VssFreeSnapshotProperties(&snapshotProperties);

for( SnapshotIdList::iterator it = m_SnapshotIdList.begin(); it != m_SnapshotIdList.end(); it++ )
{
    LONG cDeletedSnapshots; 
    GUID nonDeletedSnapshotId;
    m_pBackupComponents->DeleteSnapshots(*it, VSS_OBJECT_SNAPSHOT_SET, TRUE, &cDeletedSnapshots, &nonDeletedSnapshotId); 
}

m_SnapshotIdList.clear();

for( VssSyncList::iterator it = m_VssSyncList.begin(); it != m_VssSyncList.end(); it++ )
{
    (*it).Release();
}

m_VssSyncList.clear();

CComPtr<IVssAsync> pBackupCompleteResults;
if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = m_pBackupComponents->BackupComplete(&pBackupCompleteResults))) )
{
    throw;
}
else
{
    if( !CHECK_HRESULT((hr = pBackupCompleteResults->Wait())) )
    {
        throw;
    }

    HRESULT hrBackupCompleteResults; 
    if( CHECK_HRESULT(pBackupCompleteResults->QueryStatus(&hrBackupCompleteResults, NULL)) )
    {
        if( hrBackupCompleteResults != VSS_S_ASYNC_FINISHED )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    pBackupCompleteResults.Release();
}

m_SnapshotMap.clear();
```

It seems that something I'm calling is in the wrong order but looking at the documentation and various sources I cannot figure out what is in the wrong order.

Is there anything blindingly obvious that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling SetBackupSucceeded after each component has been processed and prior to calling BackupComplete??

Comment: I'm not using component mode. The first parameter of SetBackupState is FALSE which I believe is correct for a simple file backup

Comment: Updated to contain the actual source.

Answer (score 0):

I have been caught with this errors when I was learning VSS, mostly the error was due calling the VSS sequence with CoInitialize(). Please check whether you have CoInitialize and CoUninitialize before and after the VSS sequence.

Comment: It's a multi-threaded app and I'm calling `CoInitializeEx()` in the main startup thread. Without it, all of the function calls fail.